# Java/Bukkit - Check if a player bumped into a wall

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm making a Bukkit plugin and I want to run a piece of code when a player touches a wall(with his body, not with the cross hair!) So, I think that this is possible with a PlayerMoveEvent. The question is, how.
A few notes:

- If the player looks at an other direction and he walks into a wall, I want to run the same code
- The player has to touch the wall with his body, not with his cross hair

I really can't figure this out and I couldn't find this on the web. You guys are my last hope ;)
Thanks in advance,
Bram

Comment: Is it a 3d shooter? 2d platform? or...

Comment: I may was a bit unclear, but Bukkit is a Multiplayer API for the sandbox game Minecraft

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here should __show attempts__ - Add code, what do you have at the moment, and what have you tried and doesn't work? Please take a __[tour]__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Finn, this method will be qutie server intensive to run each time a player moves, but this might be of help:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerMove(PlayerMoveEvent e)
{
    for(int x = e.getPlayer().getLocation().getBlockX() - 1; x < x + 2; x++)
    {
        for(int z = e.getPlayer().getLocation().getBlockZ() - 1; z < z + 2; z++)
        {
            Block b = e.getPlayer().getWorld().getBlockAt(x, e.getPlayer().getLocation().getBlockY(), z);

            if(b.getType() != Material.AIR)
            {
                doSomething();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In theory, that should work.  It simply loops through the blocks surrounding the player.  If they're not empty (made of air) then it will do whatever you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to first get the player's location. Then, use the X- and Z-coordinates to find out how close they are to the edge of the block they're standing on. If they're close enough (about 0.3 blocks), you will need to find out if there is a block in that direction using location vectors and Material.isSolid().
To call this method every time the player moves (or turns their head) could potentially be laggy.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with no good solution short of reimplementing mojang's checks or hooking into nms.